# Atomically Compare-Exchange a Model Field in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, atomic, compare-and-swap

How can I atomically compare-exchange-save a value of Django `Model` instance `Field`? (Using PostgreSQL as the DB backend).

An example use case is making sure multiple posts with similar content (e.g. submits of the same form) take effect only once, without relying on insecure and only sometimes-working client-side javascript or server-side tracking of form UUIDs, which isn't secure against malicious multiple-posts.

For example:

```
def compare_exchange_save(model_object, field_name, comp, exch):
    # How to implement?
    ....


from django.views.generic.edit import FormView    
from django.db import transaction
from my_app.models import LicenseCode

class LicenseCodeFormView(FormView):
    def post(self, request, ...):

        # Get object matching code entered in form
        license_code = LicenseCode.objects.get(...)

        # Safely redeem the code exactly once
        # No change is made in case of error
        try:
            with transaction.atomic()
                if compare_exchange_save(license_code, 'was_redeemed', False, True):
                    # Deposit a license for the user with a 3rd party service. Raises an exception if it fails.
                    ...
                else:
                    # License code already redeemed, don't deposit another license.
                    pass
        except:
            # Handle exception
            ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `update` function on a QuerySet object.

Depending on the value, you can do a comparison with Case, When objects - check out the docs on [conditional updates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-update) *NOTE* that link is for 1.10 - Case/When came in in 1.8.

You might also find utility in using `F` which is used to reference a value in a field.

For example:

I need to update a value in my model Model:

```
(Model.objects
 .filter(id=my_id)
 .update(field_to_be_updated=Case(
      When(my_field=True, then=Value(get_new_license_string()),
      default=Value(''),
      output_field=models.CharField())))
```

If you need to use an `F` object, just reference it on the right hand side of the equals in the update expression.

The update doesn't necessitate the use of `transaction.atomic()` context manager but if you need to do any other database operations you should continue to wrap that code with `transaction.atomic()`

Edit:

You may also like to use the queryset `select_for_update` method that implements row locks when the queryset is executed [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update).

Comment: Is this guaranteed to be atomic, though? I don't see that in the docs. If it isn't, then in my use case it's possible for two different requests to enter the "Deposit a license" section

Comment: This is a single database call. It's as atomic as it's possible to be.

Comment: @DanielRoseman which is atomic, or not? That is, assuming a PostgreSQL backend, is it possible for two concurrent requests which call this method at the same time to both successfully update the value? Or is it guaranteed that at most one will succeed?

Comment: Added some more info on a queryset method for using locks in your call.

Comment: @theWanderer4865 Thanks, great! The docs you added to select_for_update suggest that the first method you suggested would also work for the atomic compare-exchange functionality, assuming the row is locked when it is being updated, which seems to be the case assuming it is wrapped inside a transaction. (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html: "An exclusive row-level lock on a specific row is automatically acquired when the row is updated or deleted. The lock is held until the transaction commits or rolls back")

Comment: @Danra Glad to help. When I've encountered scenarios when I need to do an update for something that is modified/read consistently but only have one operation I generally go with update with the select_for_update just to sleep better at night. If I need to have something like a log for an update then I will just wrap the whole thing in a transaction.atomic() block but the supporting method for the update will still have the select_for_update - probably unnecessary but I haven't run into anything in production about bad interactions - better safe than sorry!